# How to parse json in shell script using jq add store into array in shell script

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I want to parse below json array and store property of object in array of shell script variable.

```
{
   "student_profile":[
      {
         "fname":"abc",
         "lname":"xyz"
      },
      {
         "fname":"def",
         "lname":"pqr"
      }
   ]
}
```

Below is my sh file.

```
myfile.sh

#!/bin/bash

declare -a names=()

###### Acess and parse json file here and store fname inside the name array
```

Comment: From the linked duplicate, instead of feeding input from a string using `<<<`, you use the syntax as `jq -r '.student_profile[].fname'  json_file`

Comment: `mapfile -t names < <(jq -r '.student_profile[].fname'  file.json); printf '%s\n' "${names[@]}"`